# NSDate conversion issue when input NSDate format is unknown and separate Date and Time

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I get null date even when the string that I pass has a date as shown below:-

Generic input Date Format is "MM/dd/YYYY hh:mm a"

NSString input Date can be one of the following: "12/1/2012"  , "12/1/2012 01:43 am" , "01:43 am"

Expected output which I am trying is that , it must print date if it exists in input string and time must be printed out if it exists in the input string.

Input:-

```
 [self testDate:@"12/1/2012"]
```

Code:-

```
-(void) testDate:(NSString*) str{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"];//My Generic Date Format
    self.dateTest=[formatter dateFromString:str];
    [self printDate:self.dateTest];
}


-(void) printSeparatedDateAndTime:(NSDate*) date{
    NSDateFormatter *dateF=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateF setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    NSString *dateStr=[dateF stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"Date= %@",dateStr);

    [dateF setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
    NSString *timeStr=[dateF stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"Time= %@",timeStr);
}
```

Output Date:-

Date= (null)

Time= (null)

Input can be in any format, ex

**input**
"12/1/2012"
**output**
date="12/1/2012"
time=null

**input**
"12/1/2012 01:43 am"
**output**
date="12/1/2012"
time=01:43 am

**input**
"01:43 am"
**output**
date=null
time="01:43 am"

One can get a different answer here [Objective-C String(yyyy-mm-dd) to NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985872/objective-c-stringyyyy-mm-dd-to-nsdate). This refers to answer if date format set is wrong.

In my case date format is correct. But it might have only date, only time or both of them.
To separate date and time from a String one can refer here [ios4 - splitting a date and time from a string into two separate strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883628/ios4-splitting-a-date-and-time-from-a-string-into-two-separate-strings), but it does not have a checked answer or a valid answer.

Comment: in this [self printDate:date]; what is date?

Comment: no need of `hh:mm a` if you are sending only date otherwise send the time also in the date string.

Comment: @nsgulliver as edited in the question input string can have date, time or both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `hh:mm a`  and the format can be either "MM/dd/yyyy" or "dd/MM/yyyy".

```
-(void) testDate:(NSString*) str{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    self.dateTest=[formatter dateFromString:str];
    [self printDate:date];
}
```

Your `printeDate:` will not work as expected since the date created don't have any information about the time and you are trying to show hours and minutes.It will always show 12.00 AM.

If you want to show hours and minutes you need to include that also in your input string.

EDIT : Since dateFormats can be in three formats you need to do a trial and error.

```
-(void) testDate:(NSString*) str{

    NSArray *dateFormats = @[@"dd/MM/yyyy",@"hh:mm a",@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a"];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSDate *date = nil;

    for (NSString *dateFormat in dateFormats) {
        [formatter setDateFormat:dateFormat];
        date = [formatter dateFromString:str];
        if (date) {
            break;
        }
    }

    [self printDate:date];
}
```

OR

```
-(void) testDate:(NSString*) dateString
{
    NSDate *date = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeDate
                                                               error:&error];
    NSArray *matches = [detector matchesInString:dateString
                                         options:0
                                           range:NSMakeRange(0, [dateString length])];
    for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
        if (match.date) {
            date = match.date;
            break;
        }
    }

    [self printDate:date];
}
```

EDIT 2 : As it is a requirement to have data/time to nil out. Please try

```
typedef enum {
    ValidDateType = 0,
    ValidTimeType = 1,
    ValidDateTimeType =2
}ValidType;

- (void)testDate:(NSString*) dateString
{
    NSArray *dateFormats = @[@"dd/MM/yyyy",@"hh:mm a",@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a"];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    __block NSDate *date = nil;
    __block ValidType type = ValidDateType;

    [dateFormats enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSString *dateFormat = (NSString *)obj;
        [formatter setDateFormat:dateFormat];
        date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
        if (date) {
            type = idx;
            *stop = TRUE;
        }

    }];

    [self printDate:date validType:type];
}

- (void)printDate:(NSDate*) date validType:(ValidType)type
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateF=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateF setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    NSString *dateStr=[dateF stringFromDate:date];


    [dateF setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
    NSString *timeStr=[dateF stringFromDate:date];

    dateStr = (type == ValidTimeType)?nil:dateStr;
    timeStr = (type == ValidDateType)?nil:timeStr;

    NSLog(@"Time= %@",timeStr);
    NSLog(@"Date= %@",dateStr);

}
```

Comment: Yes you are right, but looping through various format! Anything better than this.

Comment: @andyPaul I have edited my answer. If the input dateString is in a known timezone then dateDetector would work fine.

Comment: that was a nice answer. but if only time is present than date must be null. And if only date is present then time must be null. And if both are present its okie, to output both of them.

Comment: I think in that case only your first answer will work.

Comment: @andyPaul Why did you unaccept the answer?

Comment: your code works but, it does not return null for time when only date is entered and vice versa

Comment: @andyPaul I can't think of an elegant solution for your issue.Once converted date instance would have some value for data/time. You can achieve your expected behaviour but it's not very clean. If this is a must for you ,depending on the dateFormat in which you get a valid date you can decide that if date/time is valid or not. If you are okay with that I would provide code for that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28670/discussion-between-andypaul-and-anupdas)

Comment: Great Answer . Keep it up. Many geeks down voted the question instead of answering it

Answer (score 1):

You set the date format to include time: `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a`, but you are not passing any time with you string: `12/1/2012`.

Just remove the `hh:mm a` from the date format :

```
-(void) testDate:(NSString*) str{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    self.dateTest = [formatter dateFromString:str];
   [self printDate:self.dateTest];
}
```

---

Also I would suggest not using a static date format, just incase you have any non America users. Apple has added `NSDateFormatterStyle` to make it easy for you to use the user/system selected style of formatting.

```
-(void) printDate:(NSDate*) date{ 
    NSDateFormatter *dateF=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateF.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
    dateF.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
    NSString *dateStr=[dateF stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"Date= %@",dateStr);

    dateF.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
    dateF.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
    NSString *timeStr=[dateF stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"Time= %@",timeStr);
}
```